# R - Aggregating and returning value that minimises another dimension

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, aggregation

I have a data frame, with a date, a string (Keyword) and a metric (CPA).

It looks something like this:

```
Day          Keyword             CPA              
1/1/18       trip                11.88
2/1/18       trip                14.91
3/1/18       motorbike           13.68
4/1/18       motorbike           16.31
5/1/18       hotel               11.88
6/1/18       hotel               14.91
11/1/18      hotel               13.68
13/1/18      car                 16.31
```

For each Keyword string, I want to return the Day which saw the lowest CPA.

So in this case it would return:

```
Lowest CPA Day          Keyword            
1/1/18                  trip                          
3/1/18                  motorbike                    
5/1/18                  hotel                        
13/1/18                 car
```

i can return the lowest CPA:

```
report_CPA_lowest <- report_CPA %>% select(Keyword, CPA) %>%
                                    group_by(Keyword) %>%
                                    summarise(
                                      lowest_CPA = min(CPA)
                                    ) %>% arrange(lowest_CPA)
```

but when i attempt to return the day, i fail:

```
report_CPA_lowest <- report_CPA %>% select(Keyword, CPA) %>%
                                    group_by(Keyword) %>%
                                    summarise(
                                      lowest_CPA_date = which(Day == min(CPA))
                                    ) %>% arrange(lowest_CPA_date)
```

Would be appreciate any suggestion of a  better way of doing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Loading the data for reproducibility)

```
library(dplyr)

report_CPA <- read.table(text = "
Day          Keyword             CPA              
1/1/18       trip                11.88
2/1/18       trip                14.91
3/1/18       motorbike           13.68
4/1/18       motorbike           16.31
5/1/18       hotel               11.88
6/1/18       hotel               14.91
11/1/18      hotel               13.68
13/1/18      car                 16.31", header = TRUE)
```

You need to access the values with `[` `]`. You can also use `which.min` instead of the more general `which` in this case.

```
report_CPA %>%
  group_by(Keyword) %>%
  summarise(
    lowest_CPA = min(CPA),
    lowest_CPA_date = Day[which.min(CPA)]
  )
```

Output:

```
  Keyword   lowest_CPA lowest_CPA_date
  <fct>          <dbl> <fct>          
1 trip            11.9 1/1/18         
2 car             16.3 13/1/18        
3 motorbike       13.7 3/1/18         
4 hotel           11.9 5/1/18
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
df %>% group_by(Keyword) %>% slice(which.min(CPA))

## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   Keyword [4]
#  Day     Keyword     CPA
#  <fct>   <fct>     <dbl>
#1 13/1/18 car        16.3
#2 5/1/18  hotel      11.9
#3 3/1/18  motorbike  13.7
#4 1/1/18  trip       11.9
```

This will simply select the (first) row with a minimum CPA per Keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `dplyr::top_n`**

```
library(dplyr)
report_CPA %>%
  group_by(Keyword) %>%
  top_n(-1,CPA)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   Keyword [4]
#   Day     Keyword     CPA
#   <fct>   <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 1/1/18  trip       11.9
# 2 3/1/18  motorbike  13.7
# 3 5/1/18  hotel      11.9
# 4 13/1/18 car        16.3
```

The negative indice means you filter on the smallest value.

**In base R**

```
do.call(rbind, by(report_CPA,report_CPA$Keyword,function(x)x[which.min(x$CPA),]))
```

or

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(report_CPA, report_CPA$Keyword),function(x)x[which.min(x$CPA),]))
#               Day   Keyword   CPA
# car       13/1/18       car 16.31
# hotel      5/1/18     hotel 11.88
# motorbike  3/1/18 motorbike 13.68
# trip       1/1/18      trip 11.88
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

input <- as.data.table(input) # 2018-01-01
input[, Day := as.POSIXct(Day)]
input[, .(minCPA = min(CPA), minDate = min(Day)), by = .(Keyword)][]

     Keyword minCPA             minDate
1:      trip  11.88 2018-01-01 03:00:00
2: motorbike  13.68 2018-01-03 03:00:00
3:     hotel  11.88 2018-01-05 03:00:00
4:       car  16.31 2018-01-13 03:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Once arranged, `slice` the first value

```
  report_CPA %>% 
  group_by(Keyword) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Keyword, CPA)) %>% 
  slice(1)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   Keyword [4]
#>   Day     Keyword     CPA
#>   <fct>   <fct>     <dbl>
#> 1 13/1/18 car        16.3
#> 2 5/1/18  hotel      11.9
#> 3 3/1/18  motorbike  13.7
#> 4 1/1/18  trip       11.9
```

Created on 2018-07-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).